# Determine the type of IIS websites

Tags: c#, iis, windows-services, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I am writing a windows service in c# which runs on every server containing "Windows Server 2003". Purpose of this service is to check all the IIS websites and their types. For the current scenario, we only have two types, One is php and other is ASP.Net

Is there any way to get that? or any other possible alternate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS web sites don't have a `type`.

A site can run both `asp.net` and `php` at the same time.

Just because `asp.net` and `php` is enabled for a site, doesn't mean it is actually used.

So you don't need to look at IIS but at the content files. Do you see `*.php`, `*.aspx` or `*.cshtml` files?

By looking at the file extensions you should be able to determine what type of technology is used.

Comment: How can I access the content files via C#? I can access the website names in Default Websites by using DirectoryEntry. How to access the pages?

Comment: Whole different question, search for managing files with C#, use the System.IO namespace.